# Why johnson algorithm gives optimum sequence

Tags: algorithm, optimization

The Johnson algorithm for Job shop scheduling solves the case of 2 machines and N jobs

Job Pi has two operations, of duration Pi1, Pi2, to be done on Machine M1, M2 in that sequence.

```
Step 1. List A = { 1, 2, …, N }, List L1 = {}, List L2 = {}.
Step 2. From all available operation durations, pick the minimum.
If the minimum belongs to Pk1,
Remove K from list A; Add K to end of List L1.
If minimum belongs to Pk2,
Remove K from list A; Add K to beginning of List L2.
Step 3. Repeat Step 2 until List A is empty.
Step 4. Join List L1, List L2. This is the optimum sequence.
```

I do not understand why this is giving "optimum" answer. Here is the [wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_shop_scheduling)

I think this is a counter example:

Job sets:

(2,3);(4,5);(6,7)

The final answer algorithm gives is J1,J2,J3(2,4,6) on Machine 1, while Machine 2 remains idle all the time. Instead if we scheduled J1,J2 on machine 1 and J3 on machine 2 then we could have done it earlier

Can anyone explain what am I doing wrong.

Comment: @downvoter: I have a doubt I asked it. I gave a counter example for the same so I have done some homework. I understand that I might be wrong. If you are so confident please provide an answer. I don't care for downvotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The final answer algorithm gives is J1,J2,J3(2,4,6) on Machine 1, while Machine 2 remains idle all the time. Instead if we scheduled J1,J2 on machine 1 and J3 on machine 2 then we could have done it earlier.

No. The point is that the jobs consist of two parts, and the first part must be done on machine 1, the second, *after the first is finished*, on the second machine.

So in your example, You'd get the sequence `{ J1, J2, J3 }`, that is right, and it would be executed

1. `J1[1]` on M1; 2 minutes
2. `J2[1]` on M1, and `J1[2]` on M2, started at the same time; 4 minutes and 3 minutes
3. `J3[1]` on M1, and `J2[2]` on M2, started - coincidentally, since `J2[1] > J1[2]` - at the same time; 6 minutes and 5 minutes
4. `J3[2]` on M2; 7 minutes

so altogether you need `2 + 4 + 6 + 7 = 19` minutes, and that's the fastest possible way.

The target is to maximise the overlap between the activity on M1 and on M2. So if you have jobs with short first parts, do them first to get machine 2 occupied as soon as possible. And if possible, have jobs with short second part last, so that the time when machine 2 does work while machine 1 has already finished is small.

Comment: My bad. took it as job i can be executed on either machine and get completed.